# How to append multiple JSON object in a custom list using python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionary (business  and business 1). I convert this dictionary into JSON file as (a and b). Then i append this two JSON object in a custom list called "all".
Here, list creation is static, i have to make it dynamic because the number of dictionary could be random. But output should be in same structure.

**Here is my code section**

## Python Code

```
import something as b
business = {
"id": "04",
"target": b.YesterdayTarget,
'Sales': b.YSales,
'Achievements': b.Achievement
}

business1 = {
"id": "05",
"target": b.YesterdayTarget,
'Sales': b.YSales,
'Achievements': b.Achievement
}



# Convert Dictionary to json data
a= str(json.dumps(business, indent=5))
b= str(json.dumps(business1, indent=5))

all = '[' + a + ',\n' + b + ']'
print(all)
```

**Output Sample**

```
[{
 "id": "04",
 "target": 55500000,
 "Sales": 23366927,
 "Achievements": 42.1
 },
 {
 "id": "05",
 "target": 55500000,
 "Sales": 23366927,
 "Achievements": 42.1
 }]
```

**Thanks for your suggestions and efforts.**

Comment: Are they in newlines?

Comment: A noble goal you have. What have you attempted? Please post your code and explain why you are not happy with it.

Comment: **Yes, A and B dictionary are in a separate lines **    @Ava

Comment: @DYZ, I am going to create Alexa skills, to make it dynamic i have to append all new and updated dictionary  in a list like main = [ {all dictionary are in here} ]

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. You must demonstrate your effort by posting your code, even if your code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```py
import ast, re

lines = open(path_to_your_file).read().splitlines()
result = [ast.literal_eval(re.search('({.+})', line).group(0)) for line in lines]

print(len(result))
print(result)
```

Comment: It is considered bad practice on SO to answer questions that do not demonstrate any effort.

Comment: @DYZ sorry, I just wanted to help. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks @DYZ, for your valuable comments. I will try to make it more descriptive in next time. If you have some time please have a look at my code.